# Unable to select a value from a dropdown of windows form using AutoIt

Tags: vb.net, testing, automation, autoit

Using the following code

```
ControlCommand("Test Form", "", "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", "ShowDropDown")
ControlSend("Test Form", "", "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", "This is my default value (TEST) - First")

or

ControlCommand("Test Form", "", "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", "ShowDropDown")
ControlSend("Test Form", "", "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", "select", "This is my default value (TEST) - First")
```

It selects the combo box, but it is not selecting the desired "this is my default value (TEST) - First" from the list. Basically, it is selecting any value that starts with `t`. For example, the first value is "TMP". So instead of exactly matching it is selecting any first character match. How do I force it to select the exact string from the list?

I also tried using the following code, but nothing seems to work.

```
WinWaitActive($title)
$Index = _GUICtrlComboBoxEx_FindStringExact($hcombo, $sText)
_GUICtrlComboBoxEx_SetCurSel($hcombo, $Index)
or following
WinWaitActive($title)
$Index = _GUICtrlComboBox_FindStringExact($hcombo, $sText)
_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($hcombo, $Index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are using [ControlSend](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) with incorrect parameters. The following will send the string 'select', and the last parameter will be evaluated to 0.

```
ControlSend("Test Form", "", "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", "select", "This is my default value (TEST) - First")
```

As it expects 1 or 0 as the last parameter). Needless to say it's not what you want.

You should be doing something like SelectString with [ControlCommand](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlCommand.htm). You shouldn't have to show the dropdown first:

```
ControlCommand("Test Form", "", "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]", "SelectString", "This is my default value (TEST) - First")
```

I haven't been able to test that, but as long as it's finding the window and the string is correct then it should be fine.

Comment: @sam, and this is definitely a standard combo, and that string definitely exists? It could be that the combo is populated on the dropdown event, but I doubt it.